# Continuity proof help

Tags: analysis

[image: x]
![x]

could someone please explain to me why:

1) You can choose $\epsilon = 1$ are we not trying to prove it for any epsilon?

2) Why if $h\leq 0$ bounds f on $[0,\infty)$

3) how they got if $ h > 0$ then $[0,h]$?

I really can't figure it out

Comment: The solution is applying the definition of the hypothesis $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ with $\epsilon = 1$. That is the _assumption_, not what they're trying to prove.

Comment: For 1), you are not trying to *prove* continuity – you are supposed to be *using* it. And for that, a sincle $\epsilon$ is sometimes enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to prove that $f$ is bounded.

We know that on a compact set, that $f$ is bounded.

The issue is that $[0, \infty)$ is not compact, however, since $f$ converges to $0$ as $ x \to \infty$, this means that we can make $|f|$ as small as we want if $x$ is sufficiently large.

To show that $f$ is bounded, we can pick any number (not necessarily one) $B>0$, then for $x$ large enough, say $x > M$,  we will have $|f| \le B$. Then we need only consider $f$ for $x \le M$. Since $[0,M]$ is compact, we know there is some other bound $B'$ such that $|f(x)| \le B'$ for $ x\in [0,M]$.

Hence $|f(x)| \le \max(B,B')$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

1) The continuity of the function is assumed, not being proved.

2) For any x larger than h, $f(x)\le 1$. if $h \le 0$, so for any positive x $f(x)\le 1$, so the function is bounded.

3) If $0\le h$, the proof divided to proof that f is bounded in $[0,h]$ and that it is bounded in $(h, \infty)$